# No action bar with Theme.MaterialComponents

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-components-android

I am running an old Android app through lint, prior to issuing an updated version.

Lint recommended changing Switch to SwitchMaterial: I did this, and got a runtime error when the app tried to invoke SwitchMaterial, saying that the theme must be Theme.MaterialComponent.

I replaced AppTheme with this:

```
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge" >
```

Now I don't get an ActionBar (no space is allocated, and getActionBar returns null).

What do I have to do, to get my ActionBar back?